# Scrapy: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to get product title,link,price in category https://tiki.vn/dien-thoai-may-tinh-bang/c1789

But it fails "HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed":

[image: error log]

My file: spiders/tiki.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule

from stackdata.items import StackdataItem


class StackdataSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "tiki"
    allowed_domains = ["tiki.vn"]
    start_urls = [
        "https://tiki.vn/dien-thoai-may-tinh-bang/c1789",
    ]

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=r"\?page=2"),
             callback="parse_item", follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        questions = response.xpath('//div[@class="product-item"]')

        for question in questions:
            question_location = question.xpath(
                '//a/@href').extract()[0]
            full_url = response.urljoin(question_location)
            yield scrapy.Request(full_url, callback=self.parse_question)

    def parse_question(self, response):
        item = StackdataItem()
        item["title"] = response.css(
            ".item-box h1::text").extract()[0]
        item["url"] = response.url
        item["content"] = response.css(
            ".price span::text").extract()[0]
        yield item
```

File: items.py

```
import scrapy


class StackdataItem(scrapy.Item):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
```

Please help me!!!! thanks!

Comment: Hi @Gait, please accept the answer if it solved your problem. Otherwise let us know how the community can further support you!

Answer (score 47):

### tl;dr

You are being blocked based on scrapy's user-agent.

You have two options:

1. Grant the wish of the website and do not scrape them, or
2. Change your user-agent

I assume you want to take option 2.

Go to your `settings.py` in your scrapy project and set your user-agent to a non-default value. Either your own project name (it probably should not contain the word `scrapy`) or a standard browser's user-agent.

```
USER_AGENT='my-cool-project (http://example.com)'
```

### Detailed error analysis

We all want to learn, so here is an explanation of how I got to this result and what you can do if you see such behavior again.

The website *tiki.vn* seems to return [HTTP status 404](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) for all requests of your spider. You can see in your screenshot that you get a 404 for both your requests to `/robots.txt` and `/dien-thoai-may-tinh-bang/c1789`.

404 means "not found" and web servers use this to show that a URL does not exist. However, if we check the same sites manually, we can see that both sites contain valid content. Now, it could technically be possible that these sites return both content and a 404 error code at the same time, but we can check this with the developer console of our browser (e.g. Chrome or Firefox).

[image]

Here we can see that robots.txt returns a valid 200 status code.

### Further investigations to be done

Many web sites try to restrict scraping, so they try to detect scraping behavior. So, they will look at some indicators and decide if they will serve content to you or block your request. I assume that exactly this is what's happening to you.

I wanted to crawl one website, which worked totally fine from my home PC, but did not respond at all (not even 404) to any request from my server (scrapy, wget, curl, ...).

Next steps you'll have to take to analyze the reason for this issue:

- Can you reach the website from your home PC (and do you get Status code 200)?
- What happens if you run scrapy from your home PC? Still 404?
- Try to load the website from the server, on which you run scrapy (e.g. with wget or curl)

You can fetch it with wget like this:

```
wget https://tiki.vn/dien-thoai-may-tinh-bang/c1789
```

wget does send a custom user-agent, so you might want to set it to a [web browser's user-agent](https://techblog.willshouse.com/2012/01/03/most-common-user-agents/) if this command does not work (it does from my PC).

```
wget -U 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36' https://tiki.vn/dien-thoai-may-tinh-bang/c1789
```

This will help you to find out if the problem is with the server (e.g. they blocked the IP or a whole IP range) or if you need to make some modifications to your spider.

### Checking the user-agent

If it works with wget for your server, I would suspect the user-agent of scrapy to be the problem. [According to the documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#user-agent), scrapy does use `Scrapy/VERSION (+http://scrapy.org)` as the user-agent unless you set it yourself. It's quite possible that they block your spider based on the user-agent.

So, you have to go to `settings.py` in your scrapy project and look for the settings `USER_AGENT` there. Now, set this to anything which does not contain the keyword `scrapy`. If you want to be nice, use your project name + domain, otherwise use a standard browser user-agent.

Nice variant:

```
USER_AGENT='my-cool-project (http://example.com)'
```

Not so nice (but common in scraping) variant:

```
USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
```

In fact, I was able to verify that they block on the user-agent with this wget command from my local PC:

```
wget -U 'Scrapy/1.3.0 (+http://scrapy.org)' https://tiki.vn/dien-thoai-may-tinh-bang/c1789
```

which results in

```
--2017-10-14 18:54:04--  https://tiki.vn/dien-thoai-may-tinh-bang/c1789
Loaded CA certificate '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'
Resolving tiki.vn... 203.162.81.188
Connecting to tiki.vn|203.162.81.188|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2017-10-14 18:54:06 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: I am trying to crawl data from another website and had the same issue. Changing the USER_AGENT works well for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the [Aufziehvogel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46747093/2869160) user agent change, please refer the http error code also. In your case http error code is 404, which indicates a CLIENT ERROR([NOT FOUND](https://httpstatuses.com/404)).

If the website requires an authenticated session to scrape the content then the http error code might be 401 which indicates a CLIENT ERROR([UNAUTHORIZED](https://httpstatuses.com/401))

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your user-agent using the following command:

```
scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT='custom user agent' 'http://www.example.com'
```

Sometimes, the websites block specific user-agents to prevent from crawling and sending too many requests. Then you can see whether it works or not using `view(response)` command.

For the class-based implementation [@Aufziehvogel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46747093/7310077) tells the story very complete!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other two good answers, try the following:

1. Set the value of `'Redirect_enabled':`  to `true`
2. Use `https` or `http` protocols.
3. Use or remove www prefix.

Comment: Where would one set `'Redirect_enabled'`: to `true`?