# Scrapy: getting HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed only when crawling

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I am getting the above mentioned error when trying to crawl a website. There are many posts on SO with similar issue, most notably this one: [Scrapy: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46746701/scrapy-http-status-code-is-not-handled-or-not-allowed) where it is suggested to change the user agent to prevent this error. However, my issue is a bit different. I did change the user agent and I am still unable to run `scrapy crawl spidername` command, but I am able to run `scrapy shell "website.com"` without an issue and I am even able to get the response from the website inside the shell and parse the html. The error only happens when I try to run `crawl` command.

What could be the issue? Here is my error message:

[image]

I am even able to run `spider` object from inside the shell without any errors.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might sound strange but remove the trailing slash from the url and it works

Use this https://www.cigabuy.com/consumer-electroincs-c-56_75.html

and not this https://www.cigabuy.com/consumer-electroincs-c-56_75.html/

Comment: wow, that was the issue. I was 100% confident there werent any issues with the spider object or parse() method itself since I could get it working from inside the shell. Thanks.